# I am not able to play the mp3 file from my local storage in android

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage, uri, android-mediaplayer

I have my mp3 files in a folder and saved it in a particular path, I am not able to play the file from my code. How to play it?

```
String filePath = (File.separator+"storage"+File.separator+"emulated"+File.separator+"0"+File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_gb" + File.separator + fileName).toString();
                final File file = new File(filePath);
                Uri uri_path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                if (uri_path!=null) {
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri_path.getPath());
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();                           
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

My Log cat Error is:

```
 System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5.Fragment.DetailPageFragment.playSound(DetailPageFragment.java:523)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5.Util.JavaScriptInterface.checkUsUkExampleSoundButton(JavaScriptInterface.java:292)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-14 13:03:27.896 28522-30026/com.mobifusion.android.ldoce5 W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: can you show logcat?

Comment: before `.start()` , you always need to `.prepare()` o else it will give you error. anyways update you question with logs

Comment: tried using .prepare() also same issue facing

Comment: seems like you have not initialized your `MediaPlayer` object. thats why you getting nullpointer exception

Comment: i think your path returns null. check the path

Comment: my file path is /sdcard/Android/obb/convertMp3ToDb/ldoce6_hwd_gb/ from that path I am trying to play a single file by using the fileName

Answer (score 1):

Create path like this

`File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/FolderName/SubFolder/xyz.mp3");`

You dont have to create or Parse it into uri

```
final File file = new File(path);
  if (file !=null) {
       try {
             // make sure mediaPlayer is not null here if(mediaPlayer != null)
             // use prepareAsync which will let you know when media is ready to be played
             // Also add mediaPlayer Exceptions in catch block
             if(mediaPlayer != null){
                 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
                 mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
             }else{
                // you can use context in mediaPlayer constructor but if dont have use like below
                 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(ActivityName.this);
                 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
                 mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
             }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }



public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Understand mediaPlayer architecture [**here.**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

[image]

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference , this issue I am facing

Comment: check this condition `if(mediaPlayer != null){  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());}`

Comment: my mediaPlayer is null what to do? So that my mediaPlayer plays

Comment: I have more than 50 k mp3 files in that folder i need to play a single file by using its fileName

Comment: just provide the full address to the file which has to be played. `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/50KMUSICFolder/FirstFile.mp3");`

Comment: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117296/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-mahalakshmi-saravanan).

Comment: still I am facing that issue can u pls help in it

Comment: I am not able to find where the issue is because i tried all the methods while debugging after setDatasource i am facing exception in all cases

Answer (score 0):

1.Need to add `prepare()` before `start()`

```
   MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
    try{  
        mp.setDataSource(uri_path.getPath());  
        mp.prepare();  
        mp.start();  

     }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

2. Check your file Path is correct or not.

this may helps you

Comment: after setDataSource function Its throwing IOException

Answer (score 0):

this is how you need to intialise and start media player.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

source [googel documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)